# Sum of single column for different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I have two columns in my table **colum#1** is `varchar(MAX)` and column#2 is `int`.

In **column#2** I have negative and positive entries I want sum of positive entries in one column and sum of negative entries in other column in my select query

To achieve this I did

```
SELECT SUM(atbl.M),SUM(atbl.p)    
from (select M=case when column#2<0 
                    then column#2 else 0 end,
             P=case when column#2 > 0 
                    then column#2 else 0 end 
        from testTable) atbl
```

or

```
select SUM(case when column#2<0 then column#2 else 0 end) as M
      ,SUM(case when column#2 > 0 then column#2 else 0 end) as P 
 from testTable
```

Is there any better way to achieve this.

Comment: No - there's no better way. I like your second query better.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it frequently on that column then use a view:

```
create view testView as
select
    sum(case when column#2 < 0 then column#2 else 0 end) as M,
    sum(case when column#2 > 0 then column#2 else 0 end) as P
from testTable
```